# svn post-commit hook fails

Tags: apache-http-server, svn

Scenario:

My repo-drupal - /var/www/svn/drupal : accessible via http//a.b.c.d/repos/drupal

working copy 1- /var/www/html/drupal-wc

working copy 2- /var/www/html/drupal-site

Both are exact svn checkouts of the repo created by "svn co http//a.b.c.d/repos/drupal /var/www/html/drupal-wc" . I work on drupal-wc, commit to it. This commit triggers post commit hook in repo which is configured to svn update drupal-site so final changes are seen here. http//a.b.c.d is configured to have DocRoot as /var/www/html/drupal-site and is coming up fine.

For testing when I add a file to drupal-wc and commit to it, I'm getting this error:

**Warning: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://a.b.c.d/repos/drupal': could not connect to server http://a.b.c.d**

The post-commit script:

/usr/bin/svn update /var/www/html/drupal-site

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

var/www/html/drupal-site  -- do svn have write permissions to this folder ?

Svn should be run as a user who has write permissions to that folder or  ..

```
`chown -R username:username /var/www/html/drupal-site `
```

where username is the name of the user running svn in the server .

Comment: It is already owned by web server user.